# Bitbucket branch source plugin fails to scan if jenkinsfile doesnt exist

Tags: jenkins, plugins, bitbucket, cloudbees, bitbucket-pipelines

i have Bitbucket team project set up to scan the organization folder and create the pipelines, but in absence of Jenkinsfile the job fails

```
Checking branch master from UKCEP/amatch-acceptance
ERROR: [Thu Jul 04 12:59:03 UTC 2019] Could not fetch sources from navigator com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator@53f18bdb
java.io.IOException: Communication error for url: Jenkinsfile status code: 401
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.server.client.BitbucketServerAPIClient.checkPathExists(BitbucketServerAPIClient.java:478)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource$BitbucketProbeFactory$1.exists(BitbucketSCMSource.java:1478)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSourceCriteria$Probe.stat(SCMSourceCriteria.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory$1.isHead(WorkflowBranchProjectFactory.java:74)
    at jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMSourceRequest.process(SCMSourceRequest.java:342)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieveBranches(BitbucketSCMSource.java:748)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource.retrieve(BitbucketSCMSource.java:589)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:373)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:327)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProjectFactory$BySCMSourceCriteria.recognizes(MultiBranchProjectFactory.java:263)
    at jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder$SCMSourceObserverImpl$1.recognizes(OrganizationFolder.java:1404)
    at jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder$SCMSourceObserverImpl$1.complete(OrganizationFolder.java:1419)
    at jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMNavigatorRequest.process(SCMNavigatorRequest.java:254)
    at jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMNavigatorRequest.process(SCMNavigatorRequest.java:204)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator.visitSources(BitbucketSCMNavigator.java:479)
    at jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder.computeChildren(OrganizationFolder.java:488)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:277)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:164)
    at jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder$OrganizationScan.run(OrganizationFolder.java:968)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
[Thu Jul 04 12:59:03 UTC 2019] Finished organization scan. Scan took 11 sec
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of EU Keying and Linking
java.io.IOException: Communication error for url: Jenkinsfile status code: 401
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.server.client.BitbucketServerAPIClient.checkPathExists(BitbucketServerAPI
```

Expected result: the repositories which don't have Jenkinsfile should be ignored 
Actual output: the failure error mentioned above

Jenkins version: 2.1.83
Bitbucket branch source plugin version: 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

If there is another file for marking the repository is valid for build, you can use Remote File Plugin for that.

In this plugin there is a field called `Local File`. If you define a file name here, like `pom.xml`, only repositories and branches which has this file will be created.

This is from the documentation of the plugin.

`When using Remote File Plugin, you might want to build only repositories and branches which contain a certain file. In this case, you may specify a Local File in the Plugin SCM Definition. This way, Jenkins will create projects only for repositories and branches containing the file you specified.`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the plugin will try to read all the branches and which don't have JenkinsFile build will fail. To overcome it, for all testing branches(which you don't want to build the Jobs), you have to maintain the different branch names not similar to actual branches(Which you want to build).

And in the Job configuration, you can have regular expression matching to your actual branches, so that Jenkins will ignore the remaining branches.

For more details, check https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/bitbucket